# javascript replace characters

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace all occurent of "-", ":" characters and spaces from a string that appears in this format:

```
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
```

something like:

```
var date = this.value.replace(/:-/g, "");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".replace(/:|-/g, "")`

Comment: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".replace(/\s|:|-/g, "")`.  The `|` means "OR".

Comment: `/:|-| /g`. You just pipe another one. But I'd go for @Rocket's solution if you have more characters, because it looks better

Answer (score 2):

`/:-/g` means `":" followed by "-"`.  If you put the characters in `[]` it means `":" or "-"`.

```
var date = this.value.replace(/[:-]/g, "");
```

If you want to remove spaces, add `\s` to the regex.

```
var date = this.value.replace(/[\s:-]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex you want is *probably*:

```
/[\s:-]/g
```

Example of usage:

```
"YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".replace(/[\s:-]/g, '');
```

`[]` blocks match any of the contained characters.

Within it I added the `\s` pattern that matches space characters such as a space  and a tab `\t` (not sure if you want tabs and newlines, so i went with tabs and skipped newlines).

It seems you already guessed that you want the `g`lobal match which allows the regex to keep replacing matches it finds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a character class or an `|` (or):

```
var date = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".replace(/[:-\s]/g, '');

var date = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".replace(/:|-|\s/g, '');
```